# O.K. abbreviation for "On Key' in telegraphy?

Tags: abbreviations

I have a background in amateur radio and the story was always told that O.K. stood for On Key, which is what telegraphists would send in Morse Code when they returned from a break. ie I am now On Key and ready to receive.

When I went looking for confirmation of this story today I could find none.

Has anyone else heard this or is it a local myth?  What we Australians would call a Furphy.  (look that one up :-)  )

I have of course read the many other derivations for O.K.

Comment: This is perhaps less far-fetched than "Oll Korrect" or "Old Kinderhook" but still doesn't seem very plausible to me,

Comment: Yeah, it's superficially possible, but, especially given the love of legend among radio operators, seems unlikely, given the lack of "paper trail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience every  word has one or more etymologies, and the lack of one that is highly plausible, rather than putting people off, simply encourages etymologies of varying plausibility.

This is the situation we have here, with a myriad of suggestions, often presented by their proponents as 'obviously true'.

This suggestion, however, seems to have more merit than most. At least the semantic shift required is small, there would almost certainly have been some phrase meaning 'here and ready' and it could definitely be abbreviated to a a short string of letters that had no other meaning.

Since this etymology has not caught on, I am not holding my breath to find the evidence of where and when *On Key* was used, when it was abbreviated, when the term got out into the wild, and so on.

What makes me particularly unhopeful is that there were, until fairly recently, a large number of people around who had served in WWII, and many (including my father) learnt to use Morse. They would have learnt from older people who would have learnt from older people, all the way back to the the first telegraph service. The fact that this etymology is not popular amongst this group - anywhere in the world, so far as I know - seriously limits its prospects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. For lack of any other feedback, I am going to accept this answer.